# ProtocolBuffer C++ Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, cmake, visual-studio-2019, protocol-buffers, protobuf-c

I am trying to build Protocolbuffer for Visual Studio 2019 x86,

I followed the steps in this page
https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/main/cmake/README.md

for release I tried:

```
cmake -G "NMake Makefiles" ^
 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ^
 -DCMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM=Win32 ^
 -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:\protocolbuffers\install ^
 C:\protocolbuffers\protobuf
```

I have the error

> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:24 (project):   Generator
>
> ```
> NMake Makefiles
> ```
>
> does not support platform specification, but platform
>
> ```
> Win32
> ```
>
> was specified.
>
> CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage CMake
> Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage

if I removed the `-DCMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM=Win32 ^` I can create the correct files but when I compile the error is

> protocolbuffers\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\extension_set_unittest.cc(871):
> note: see reference to function template instantiation 'int
> google::protobuf::internal::RepeatedFieldLowerClampLimit<int64_t,4>(void)'
> being compiled NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin\cmake.exe"'
> : return code '0x2' Stop. NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program
> Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x86\nmake.exe"'
> : return code '0x2' Stop. NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program
> Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x86\nmake.exe"'
> : return code '0x2' Stop.

I need to create the lib files for:

> libprotobuf.lib, libprotobuf-lite.lib, libprotoc.lib

and

> protoc.exe

Comment: Read from _"The Visual Studio generator is multi-configuration: "_ in the link you provided.  It looks like you are not using the optimum generator.

Comment: @RichardCritten when I tried to create the solution it created only for x64, when I added the platform to x86 I had a lot of build errors

Comment: You don't have the full error message in your question... just a note about where the error occurred.

Comment: @AlexReinking so I used cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -A Win32 ^
 -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:\protocolbuffers\install ^
 C:\protocolbuffers\protobuf and the solutions is created correctly I have one error : `src\google/protobuf/repeated_field.h(81,27): error C2338:
2>C:\protocolbuffers\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\extension_set_unittest.cc(871): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'int 'google::protobuf::internal::RepeatedFieldLowerClampLimit<int64_t,4>(void)' being compiled
2>Done building project "tests.vcxproj" -- FAILED. `

Comment: I unload the Test projects so I can use the libs, which was created correctly